# How do format a date/time/number/currency in another locale?

Tags: windows, winapi, localization, internationalization

How do i format something for another locale in Windows?

For example, in managed C# code, i would try to render a `DateTime` using `en-US` locale with:

```
String s = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

TextRenderer.DrawText(
      e.Graphics, s, SystemFonts.IconTitleFont, 
      new Point(16, 16), SystemColors.ControlText);
```

And that works fine when my computer's locale is `en-US`:

[image]

It even works fine when my computer's locale is `de-DE`:

[image]

But it completely falls apart when my computer's locale is `ps-AF`:

[image]

**Note:** My sample code is in .NET, but can also be native.

---

**Update**: Attempting to set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to `en-US` before calling `DrawText`:

```
var oldCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
try
{
//  String s = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
    String s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, s, SystemFonts.IconTitleFont, new Point(16, 16), SystemColors.ControlText);
}
finally         
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture;
}
```

[image]

No help.

- Nine, no help
- Jack, no help
- Eight, possible straight
- King, possible flush
- Ace, no help
- Six, possible straight
- Dave of love for the dealer

Ace bets.

---

**Update Two:**

From Michael Kaplan's blog entry:

> ### [Sometimes, GDI respects users (even if no one else does!)](http://www.siao2.com/2008/06/16/8603298.aspx)
>
> GDI doesn't give a crap about formatting or really anything related to locales, with one single exception:
>
> **Digit Substitution**
>
> Any time you go to render text it will grab those digit substitution settings in the user locale (including the user override information) and use the info to decide how to display numbers.
>
> And there is no way to override those settings at the level where GDI uses them.

i wonder how **Chrome** manages it. When i write digits here, in the stackoverflow question, Chrome renders them using latin digits:

```
0123456789
```

See:

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's just using the Arabic font for the numbers - check the title - "Form" with the glyph for "1".

Comment: @ChrisF i actually did know that; but didn't want to taint the possible answers by leading someone down the wrong path. Different cultures have different "*native digits*". English uses `0123456789`, arabic uses `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`. In India it's `০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯`, unless you speak Gujarati where it's `૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯`; but then there's also Kannada (`೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯`)...et cetera et cetera

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is due to the [digit substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that occurs when your system's locale is `ps-AF`.

I believe that's OK -- Users of such a locale are used to seeing digits presented this way.

Normally the way this is done is slightly different, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syy068tk.aspx) for example, but I don't actually think this should make any difference:

```
String s = DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: When i'm generating the output (e.g. pdf invoice, image chart) i need to use the digits *of* the target locale (i.e. the text isn't rendered on their machine, it's rendered on mine)

Comment: I see. For string content the run-time culture at the time of creation shouldn't matter as far as digit substitution is concerned, but when you render an image of course this is problematic. Please see my other answer, I suggest you try setting `Thread.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: The hint is that **Google Chrome** is able to render numbers using a target locale - not suffering from digit substitution. How does Chrome do it?

Comment: I think the answer is that Google Chrome isn't written in .NET and doesn't actually use GDI--it probably renders text using Direct2D (which has some differences with GDI, particularly when it comes to internationalization)

Comment: [DirectWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to set `Thread.CurrentCulture` to your desired locale.

I.e. do this:

```
Thread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

And you can then replace the first line of your code with this:

```
String s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

I am not quite sure, but I believe that this would solve the digit substitution issue as DrawText would now be based on the `en-US` culture, rather than `ps-AF`